# Anybody ever used Virver IT Hosting?

Tags: hosting

I just heard of this company **Virver** that provides access to applications such as MS Office 2007 and MS Exchange on host server at a montly fee.  You can also put other window based applications on the server as well and have access from any where you have a internet connection and web browsers.

For 3 - 9 users there is one time setup fee of $995 and a $69/mo/user fee with 50GB of storage per user included in the monthly charge.  For 9 users at $621 per month seems really high to me.  See plans for more details https://www.virver.com/plans.html.

**Can you recomend other companies that provide the same services at better prices?**

*****Status Update***
I have done some searches on twitter and facebook and have only found one person who knows about the product but is not using.  I would really like to hear experiences from those that use Virver IT services specifically or about another company that provides the same type of service.**

Comment: SU Cross-post for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/65895/anybody-ever-use-virver-it-hosting

Comment: Wasn't sure which site this question should be posted on ...

Comment: No worries!  Sometimes it's valid on a couple of different ones and it's good to leave them on both as there are different audiences providing different input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company is actually on Virver and I wouldn't have it any other way.  While the price seems steep at first, when you factor in the redundancy, 24/7 IT support, Exchange, Office 2007, MS Communicator, MS Dynamics, and Daily Backup and monitoring; it is loads cheaper than buying a server and equipping 5 laptops with all the security and programs.  When we evaluated the solution we looked at the upfront costs of equipping employees, maintaining security, doing backups, and connecting everything through a server and after crunching the numbers found that it would cost us about 80-90% less to use Virver.

The team at Virver is unbelievable in their response times and it has made our IT solution truly hassle free. While we still have control of our environment they just do an incredible job of running things.

I'd be more than happy to share our experiences, you can check out our comapny at www.HR-4U.com.

Comment: @Brandon Dempsey - Thank for info.  I have been searching online for more info on the company and have only been able to find there company website. I would love to discuss your experiences offline.  I can be reached at www.twitter.com/AieshaDot. Thx!